# DocuSign Add User

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add users using the docuSign walkthrough and I get the following error:

```
{    
   "newUsers": [
    {
      "email": "j@hotmail.com",
      "userName": "j@hotmail.com",
      "errorDetails": {
      "errorCode": "INVALID_PASSWORD_CHALLENGE",
       "message": "Invalid forgotten password challenge."
     }
 }
]
```

}

And the request body is:

```
{
  "newUsers": [
    {
      "userSettings": [
         {
           "value": "false",
           "name": "allowSendOnBehalfOf"
         }
       ],
       "suffixName": "jr",
       "lastName": "test",
       "middleName": "test",
       "firstName": "test",
       "title": "test",
       "password": "Lagzzzz1234444",
       "userName": "j@hotmail.com",
       "email": "j@hotmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, What am I doing wrong?

I get the same error when using my own WEb API program by the way.

Comment: It means you have required forgotten password reset questions set on your account password settings, but you're not declaring them in your API call when setting the user.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, so using API, how do I disable that, what is the setting I have to set in account settings?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't used for "how do I program that or do that in an application" it's to help with smaller issues that's going on with your code. I would suggest you contact DocuSign Support for generic how-to type questions such as that.

Comment: Actually it is because I go to the API Modify User Settings and I do not see the setting for that.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew mentioned in his comment above, the error is occurring because your "Create User" request body is missing required information for ***forgottenPasswordInfo*** -- AND your DocuSign account settings currently specify that all new users must have at least 1 (or more) password reminder question/answer pairs.

If you add the **forgottenPasswordInfo** property to your request (as shown in the following example request -- except provide your own custom values for each question and answer), the user should be successfully created.

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/201105/users

{
  "newUsers": [
    {
        "lastName": "HollisterTest",
        "firstName": "Johnny",
        "password": "johnnyspassword",
        "userName": "test123ghy@hotmail.com",
        "email": "test123ghy@hotmail.com",
        "forgottenPasswordInfo": {
            "forgottenPasswordQuestion1": "This is question_1?",
            "forgottenPasswordAnswer1": "answer_1",
            "forgottenPasswordQuestion2": "This is question_2?",
            "forgottenPasswordAnswer2": "answer_2",
            "forgottenPasswordQuestion3": "This is question_3?",
            "forgottenPasswordAnswer3": "answer_3",
            "forgottenPasswordQuestion4": "This is question_4?",
            "forgottenPasswordAnswer4": "answer_4"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you do not want to have to supply the password reminder question/answer information in your "Create User" API call, you could alternatively change your DocuSign account settings such that NO password reminder questions are required for new users.  Navigate to **Preferences >> Features >> Password Strength (link)**, change the **Password Strength** dropdown to "Custom" and **Password Questions Required** to "0" (and specify other settings as you see fit):

[image: DS password settings]

**Note**: I assume that when you say this API call doesn't work in the "***DocuSign walkthrough***", you're referring to [IODocs](https://iodocs.docusign.com).  I've confirmed that there's an issue with IODocs, in that the "Create User" API call won't work unless the request body contains the **forgottenPasswordInfo** property (if DocuSign account settings require reminder Q&A) -- but IODocs doesn't expose this property in the user interface for the user to set it.  Although IODocs is a neat tool and serves as a good starting point for exploring the DocuSign REST API, it's not always 100% complete/correct for the exact situation you want to test.  Instead of relying on IODocs, it's a good idea to get accustomed to reading the [DocuSign REST API guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.docusign.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2FREST_API_Guide_v2.pdf&ei=1-8AVOu6F5CPyATy8YLQBg&usg=AFQjCNHYO27l3mWVb8xFnfAOnYpYD6reMA&sig2=xP5mBo_J6ZNz4U2HebU2AQ&bvm=bv.74115972,d.aWw) in conjunction with the [REST API help page](https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help), and to leverage a tool like Postman (in the Chrome browser) to construct and test your API calls.

Comment: Hi, ok I entered something in the forgotten password information since it wouldnt let me go through without it but now the user I add to my account gets an email, what is the setting I need to set to false using the REST API so that the user does not a notification that he has been added to the account? I went to the Add User to Account section on the docusign page and I could not see it.

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign Support for assistance with this question.

Comment: Why cant you help me?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to control this behavior via the API. Rather, I suspect it's an account setting, and perhaps a setting that you may not have access to without DocuSign specifically enabling such access. Either way, they should be able to assist...this is a product functionality question, not an API question.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, I asked DocuSign and they send me here, I do not see how to remove that notification.

Answer (score 0):

you can ask DocuSign support to Active "Silent Activation". Then when you Active Users via API, then have automaticly Status Active and they don't have to Activate their Accounts via URL in Email.

Michal